# wctomb chokes on per mille symbol (‰)

Tags: c++, locale, utf-16, multibyte, widechar

I am trying to print out a bunch of unit labels; some of them contain Greek characters, some have other funny code points.

I traced it back to the `wctomb` functions not knowing what to do with e.g. UTF-16 character 8240:

```
char mb[10]; 
assert( 0 <= wctomb(mb,8240) );
```

How can I set the locale used by `wctomb` to e.g. "All unicode characters"?

How can I find the proper locale name I need, starting from the characters I need?

Comment: seems you use Windows, which uses UTF-16 internally. So if you already have some UTF-16 string, there is no need to convert it to something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting a correct UTF-8 locale will fix it;

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");
    char mb[10]; 
    assert( 0 <= wctomb(mb,8240) );
    printf("%s\n", mb);
    return 0;
}
```

See http://ideone.com/sflZj

Comment: Oh ... setlocale returns null.

Comment: @xtofl you probably don't have `en_US.UTF-8` locale installed, try `C.UTF-8` instead.

Comment: @xtofl: This solution wont work on windows. Which OS do you use?

Comment: On Windows you shouldn't be using multi-byte encodings. There's no UTF-8 locale, and the other locales don't cover all of Unicode. CP1253 contains ‰ (`0x89`) and greek, but misses many other "funny" code points.

Comment: So after trying out all possible locale names, including "en_US.UTF-8", I reduced the locale name to "en", no luck.  Then I reduced the locale name to ""... and `setlocale` happily returns "English_United States.1252".  And I got my per mille in the console output!

Comment: @xtofl , empty string means "use default locale". So it'll use system wide settings. Just FYI.

Comment: you could try using ICU instead of stdlib strings. They have actual UTF-16 support, unlike windows.